# How do I add target=”_blank” or ”_blank” to attr() code in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

Here is code from Javascript.

```
pageElement.append($('<h2>').append($('<a>').attr('href', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + page.title).text(page.title)));
```

This code will not open in a new window. I want to open it in a new window. What do I need to add to Javascript?

Comment: use another attr ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the same way as you're setting the attr `href`

```
$(link_element).attr('target', '_blank');
```

**As Patrick mentioned:**

[attr() an object of name-value pairs,](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes)

```
.attr({target:'',href:''}) instead of doing multiple calls
```

Comment: You can also pass [`attr()` an object of name-value pairs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes), ie `.attr({target:'',href:''})` instead of doing multiple calls

Comment: It is not working. It does not open in a new window.

Comment: success: function (json) {
                var pages = json.query.pages;
                $.map(pages, function (page) {
                    var pageElement = $('<div>');

      
                    pageElement.append($('<h2>').append($('<a>').attr('href', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + page.title).text(page.title)));

            
                    pageElement.append($('<p>').text(page.extract));

                    pageElement.append($('<hr>'));

                    articles.append(pageElement);
                });
            }
        });
    };

Comment: pageElement.append($('<h2>').append($('<a>').attr({target:'', href:'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + page.title).text(page.title)});  is not working